# Can't build Selenium standalone in java 11

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, java-module

I am building a Java Selenium standalone application using Java11 in Eclipse 2018-12 but my builds fail:

> java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for
>   \selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar

I was looking into how module dependencies are defined in the latest version of java as I have been using only version 8 so far.

module-info.java:

```
module main {
    requires org.openqa.selenium.core;
}
```

mainClass:

```
package main;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class DownloadDocuments {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello!");
        WebDriver driver;
    }

}
```

Are there any additional configurations steps needed when working with modules?

The stacktrace

```
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for \selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readJar(ModulePath.java:647)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readModule(ModulePath.java:330)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.scan(ModulePath.java:236)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.scanNextEntry(ModulePath.java:189)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.findAll(ModulePath.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.ModuleFinder$2.lambda$findAll$2(ModuleFinder.java:368)
    at java.lang.module.ModuleFinder$2$$Lambda$22.00000000DB437580.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:489)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:241)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.ModuleFinder$2.findAll(ModuleFinder.java:369)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findAll(Resolver.java:841)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.bind(Resolver.java:223)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveAndBind(Configuration.java:304)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor$1.resolveAndBind(ModuleDescriptor.java:2735)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModuleBootstrap.boot(ModuleBootstrap.java:337)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.initializeClassLoaders(ClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.initialize(Thread.java:422)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:153)
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder not in module
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.deriveModuleDescriptor(ModulePath.java:554)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readJar(ModulePath.java:643)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Is there more to the stack trace?  Does it have any “Caused by” sections?

Comment: I resolved it by moving my dependencies from the modulepath to the classpath. Not sure if that is the correct solution, and if I should add this as an answer to my question.

Comment: It’s probably fine.  By using the classpath instead of the modulepath, you are telling Java to ignore modules and just treat every .jar file as a simple archive.  I admit, though, I am curious as to why the Selenium .jar could not be treated as an automatic module…

Comment: @VGR I've updated the question with a stacktrace, I am curious as well.

Comment: Strange.  That .jar (which I obtained from [here](https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.141/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar)) is a multi-release jar, so clearly it was intended to support Java 9.  When I do `jar -d -f selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar --release 9`, I see no use of service providers at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a mistake in the .jar file.  It contains a `META-INF/services/org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpFieldPreEncoder` entry, which, according to the [jar service provider interface specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), must contain the name of a class in the same .jar file which implements the interface `org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpFieldPreEncoder`.

But, as the exception states, that service descriptor file contains `org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder`, a class which does not exist in the .jar file.

There is, however, a `org.seleniumhq.jetty9.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder` class in the .jar.

The easiest way to fix this is:

- Extract the entire .jar to a temporary directory.
- Change `META-INF/services/org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpFieldPreEncoder` so it contains the single line `org.seleniumhq.jetty9.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder`.
- Create a new .jar file from the changed content.

If you’re not in Windows, you can do it on the command line:

```sh
mkdir -p META-INF/services
echo org.seleniumhq.jetty9.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder > META-INF/services/org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpFieldPreEncoder
zip -u -m selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar META-INF/services/org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpFieldPreEncoder
rm -r META-INF
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @VGR! I opened a bug report for Selenium, pointing the developers to your reply. Hopefully it is something that can be fixed upstream.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was that i only had to move the selenium.jar in my build path in libraries from modulepath to classpath.
hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me using Eclipse version 2020-06 and Java 14. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

see here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Building-WebDriver

The Java JDK 8 (note that versions 9 & 10 are not currently supported for building Selenium). Download it from Oracle's site if it's not already on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have Java8 installed, but wanted to use the latest version for a new project to benefit from the improvements it has.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem, defining all the jars in the classpath will serve the purpose.