# Eclipse settings issue

Tags: java

I'm facing an issue with selenium webdriver where firefox browser driver is showing some warning. Also, the same issue occurs with chrome browser, but I don't understanding how to fix this issue.

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\PUNET GUPTA\Downloads\selenium server\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder not in module
```

Comment: Is this a maven project?

Comment: What java version are you using?

Comment: Duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948437/cant-build-selenium-standalone-in-java-11 ?