# Would you like to replace the existing file was asked while extracting selenium-server-standalone jar file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium3

After having downloaded the selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59 jar file from https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/, I tried to extract the files. During the extraction, a pop-up shows up saying:

```
"The following file already exists. C:\Selenium3\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59\META-INF\LICENSE.txt
```

Would you like to replace the existing file [file 1 with 11.969 bytes modified on 02/11/2014 19:52] with this one [file 2 with 36.116 bytes modified on 25/04/2013 16:52]"

I then get to choose from options like 'Yes', 'Yes to all', 'No', 'No to all' etc. Why is this happening? I was expecting a normal extraction in which all files are simply extracted and no questions asked about whether to replace certain files or not. Is there a bug with this jar file? 
Please see attached screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the error...

[image: extract_selenium_jar]

while trying to extract the contents of `selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar`.

---

### Solution

If your usecase is to use *selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar* within a Java project, instead of extracting the `selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar` you need to add the jar file as an *External JAR* in the *JAVA BUILD PATH* for your project within the IDE as follows:

[image: JavaBuildPath]

Comment: I did that earlier but got a compilation error message "java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for \selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar". I then created a new selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar following the suggestion of VGR at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948437/cant-build-selenium-standalone-in-java-11/53979469#53979469. Still see the same error message and so can't run my test. I answered 'Yes to all' then 'No to all' not being sure what to pick. If this is not a desirable feature, can the developers of this jar remove these prompts?

Comment: @dmarmoset You don't extract files from a **jar**, but you need to decompile the **jar** for further usage.

Comment: The solution for my 'Unable to derive module descriptor....' error message came from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948437/cant-build-selenium-standalone-in-java-11/53979469#53979469. The first step says "Extract the entire .jar to a temporary directory." Are you saying the 'Extract' in this sentence mean decompile?

Comment: _Unable to derive module descriptor_ wasn't your question either and would have been a different question.

Comment: We have difficulty understanding each other. I've found the solution elsewhere. Thanks for trying to help.