# How to resolve this error on java with selenium?

Tags: eclipse, selenium

```
//Eclipse java code:
package openbrowser;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class OpenChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "d://chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

eclipse error

```
   Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
    java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\Om Murugaa\Downloads\Testing\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
    Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder not in module
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948437/cant-build-selenium-standalone-in-java-11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding maven into eclipse resolved this error.